# Scantxoutset: correct way to pass array in console/debug window?

Tags: bitcoin-core, scantxoutset

Ok this is a bit embarrassing but what is the standard way to pass arrays through the bitcoin debug/console window? I've done it before and I thought it just had to do with placement of quotes, but I'm having trouble doing it with `scantxoutset` I've tried the following:

```
scantxoutset start '{"desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)"}'

>>>Expected type array, got object (code -3)

scantxoutset start '["desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)"]'

>>>Error: Error parsing JSON:["desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)"]
    ￼
scantxoutset start '[{"desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)}]'

>>>Error: Error parsing JSON:[{"desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)}]

scantxoutset start '["desc":"addr","1SomeAddress"]'

>>>Error: Error parsing JSON:["desc":"addr","1SomeAddress"]

scantxoutset start '["desc",{"addr","1SomeAddress"}]'

>>>Error: Error parsing JSON:["desc",{"addr","1SomeAddress"}]
```

Comment: Try `'[{"desc":"addr(1SomeAddress)"}]'`.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't try that, that did it. Thx

Comment: doesn't work: scantxoutset start '[{"desc":"addr(37HyJsnuP5zWTuhJFvrGNYojtmBFnZYoFR)"}]'  gives error: Error parsing JSON: '[{desc:addr(37HyJsnuP5zWTuhJFvrGNYojtmBFnZYoFR)}]'